# Why my array of pointers have a segmentation fault in C?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, trie

I'm trying to make my own implementation of a trie tree to submit a list of words in C by storing the chars in arrays of chars and then to access to the next node to store the next array, each node contained in a array of nodes. But when I debug it, it seems like the connection with the next array of nodes is lost because it says it is null.

This is the struct:

```
typedef struct node {
    char c[ALLCHAR];
    struct node *next[ALLCHAR];
} listword;

listword *head;
listword *current;
```

And this is the implementation:

```
head = malloc(sizeof(listword));       //Initialize the head
current = head;                        //Pass the pointer to current
dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");         //This is the source of the words

if(dict==NULL) {
    fclose(dict);
    return 1;
}

//Here I iterate char by char in the dict
for(int c=fgetc(dict);c!=EOF;c=fgetc(dict))
{
    int myc=tolower(c)-97;          //The index equivalent to the char
    if(c=='\n') {
            current->c[27]='\0';        //The end of the word
            current=head;           //Pass the start pointer to the current
    } else {
        current->c[myc]=c;          //Here it puts the char in its position
        current=current->next[myc]; //Here I identify my problem, even 
                                    //when I already initialized next it 
                                    //appears as no value
        if(!current) {
            current=malloc(sizeof(listword)); //Here I initialize next 
                                              //if haven't initialized yet
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now is a good time to learn how to use a debugger to debug your code.  Once you have done that, and collected some relevant details, please edit your question,and post what you have found

Comment: are you sure `0 <= myc < ALLCHAR` is always true?

Comment: Does the file contain newlines? If so you will use `'\n' - 91` as an array index - kaboom! At least until it is working, I suggest checking the array index.

Comment: you aren't initializing anything in head->next. The array contains garbage data. `current = current->next[myc]`  assigns random data to `current`.

Comment: `if (dict==NULL) fclose(dict)` is a sure way to crash if the file cannot be opened.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    char data[1024];
    struct node *next;
} listword;

listword *head = NULL;


// add string to listword
void add(char *value) {
    listword *tmp;

    tmp = (listword*) malloc(sizeof(listword));
    if (tmp) {
        memcpy(tmp, value, sizeof(tmp));

        tmp->next = head;
        head = tmp;
   }
}    

// show data of listword
void show() {
    listword *tmp;

    tmp = head;
    while (tmp) {
        printf("%s\n", tmp->data);          

        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    FILE * file;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t buffer;

    // open
    file = fopen("dictionary", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    // read line of lines of file and add to listword
    while ((buffer= getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1) {
        add (line);
    }

    // close and free file
    fclose(file);
    if (line) {
        free(line);
    }

    // show data
    show ();

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: There's no use casting malloc's return in C.

Comment: The cast for `malloc` is redundant, and `sizeof(tmp)` is certainly wrong (some compilers will give you a warning for it, too).